# HostName validations and Difference with DNS Host name

Tags: java, ip-address, hostname

I have a question regarding the validations to be done on a text box where user can enter either Ip/HostName. The main question is regarding the period symbol (.). Is that allowed in a host name?

Also if period is allowed in a HostName then why does my windows OS complain :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hostnames are governed by [RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952) and amended by [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-13) where you can see that a hostname can have the form abc.def.ghi:

```
<names> ::= ... <official hostname> ...
<official hostname> ::= <hname>
<hname> ::= <name>*["."<name>]
<name>  ::= <let>[*[<let-or-digit-or-hyphen>]<let-or-digit>]
```

(I have extracted the relevant parts of the grammar in RFC952 above - RFC1123 allows the first character to be a digit also)

I believe that the alert box you're seeing is about Windows (WINS?) not allowing dots in **computer** names.

Cheers,